# Changing trigger characters in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, dart, flutter

I am using Visual Studio Code for dart/Flutter app development.

I would like to stop suggestions appearing every time I press the space bar. I don't want to disable them all together because they are handy after a '.' character and in other cases.

Does anyone know how to change the set of characters that trigger suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable or change the shortcut for that feature. 
Instructions: On you top left press:

1. Code -> preferences -> keyboard shortcuts.
2. Search for "space" keyword and change the shortcut to trigger with different keystrokes instead of just "space" button.

From Docs: [Key Bindings for Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings)

[image]

So after looking, i found more actions triggered by just "space" button. look for all of them.

[image]

Comment: I have the command "Trigger Suggest" but the binding Ctrl-Space.  Did a dart/flutter extension add a "space" keybinding for you?

Comment: Same as @Mark, I only have Ctrl + Space binding